# Problems implementing recursive best-first search in C++ based on Korf 1992

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, recursion, heap-memory

I am having two main issues implementing the algorithm described in [this article](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/AAAI/1992/AAAI92-082.pdf) in C++: properly terminating the algorithm and freeing up dynamically allocated memory without running into a seg fault.

Here is the pseudocode provided in the article:

```
RBFS (node: N, value: V, bound: B)
    IF f(N)>B, return f(N)
    IF N is a goal, EXIT algorithm
    IF N has no children, RETURN infinity
    FOR each child Ni of N,
        IF f(N) < V AND f(Ni) < V THEN F[i] := V
        ELSE F[i] := f(Ni)
    sort Ni and F[i] in increasing order of F[i]
    IF only one child, F[2] := infinity
    WHILE (F[1] <= B)
        F[1] := RBFS(N1, F[1], MIN(B, F[2]))
        insert N1 and F[1] in sorted order
    return F[1]
```

Here, f(Ni) refers to the "computed" function value, whereas F[i] refers to the currently stored value of f(Ni).

Here is my C++ implementation, in which I had to use a global variable to keep track of whether the goal had been reached or not (note, I am trying to maximize my f(n) value as opposed to minimizing, so I reversed inequalities, orders, min/max values, etc.):

```
bool goal_found = false;

bool state_cmp(FlowState *lhs, FlowState *rhs)
{
    return (lhs->value > rhs->value);
}

int _rbfs(FlowState *state, int value, int bound)
{
    if (state->value < bound) // Returning if the state value is less than bound
    {
        int value = state->value;
        delete state;
        return value;
    }
    if (state->is_goal()) // Check if the goal has been reached
    {
        cout << "Solved the puzzle!" << endl;
        goal_found = true; // Modify the global variable to exit the recursion
        return state->value;
    }
    vector<FlowState*> children = state->children();
    if (children.empty())
    {
        //delete state; // Deleting this state seems to result in a corrupted state elsewhere
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    int n = 0; // Count the number of children
    for (const auto& child: children)
    {
        if (state->value < value && child->value < value)
            child->value = value;
        else
            child->update_value(); // Equivalent of setting stored value to static value (F[i] := f(Ni))
        ++n;
    }
    sort(children.begin(), children.end(), state_cmp);
    while (children.front()->value >= bound && !goal_found) 
    {// Loop depends on the global goal_found variable since this is where the recursive calls happen
        if (children.size() < 2)
            children.front()->set_value(_rbfs(children.front(), children.front()->value, bound));
        else
            children.front()->set_value(_rbfs(children.front(), children.front()->value, max(children[1]->value, bound)));
    }
    // Free children except the front
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        delete children[i];
    state->child = children.front(); // Records the path
    return state->child->value;
}

void rbfs(FlowState* initial_state)
{
    // This is the actual function I invoke to call the algorithm
    _rbfs(initial_state, initial_state->get_value(), INT_MIN);
    print_path(initial_state);
}
```

My main questions are:

1. Is there a way to terminate this function than having to use a global variable (bool goal_reached) without a complete re-implementation? Recursive algorithms usually have some kind of base-case to terminate the function, but I am not seeing an obvious way of doing that.
2. I can't seem to delete the dead-end state (when the state has no children) without running into a segmentation fault, but not deleting it results in unfreed memory (each state object was dynamically allocated). How can I modify this code to ensure that I've freed all of the states that pass through it?

I ran the program with gdb to see what was going on, and it appears that after deleting the dead-end state, the next state that is recursively called is not actually NULL, but appears to be corrupted. It has an address, but the data it contains is all junk. Not deleting that node lets the program terminate just fine, but then many states aren't getting freed. In addition, I had originally used the classical, iterative best-first search (but it takes up far too much memory for my case, and is much slower), and in that case, all dynamically allocated states were properly freed so the issue is in this code somewhere (and yes, I am freeing each of the states on the path in main() after calling rbfs).

Comment: Regarding your first question, yes there is a way: Wrap this up in a class. That will turn the global state into local for the class instance.

Comment: I suppose that would be one way to go, but that doesn't really change the fact that I have to use some outer variable to end the recursion. Recursive functions usually have a simple base case that lets them terminate, but I'm not seeing an obvious answer to that here, which is what I am really looking for.

Comment: I see `delete` but where is `new` ?

Comment: Inside of the state->children() function. This function dynamically allocates child states and returns them in a vector<FlowState*>. I ommitted this code for brevity.

Comment: You also haven't defined `FlowState` so I can't comment on it, but if this is an enum or something simple, then dealing with the heap with `new` and `delete` is the hard way. Just use `vector<FlowState>` and forget about memory management and fiddling with pointers.

Comment: It is a very long and complicated class. I am dynamically allocating because of the large amounts of memory that I am using in the problem (this is why I switched from iterative to recursive best-first search, so I wouldn't have to keep a stack of my states).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have

```
children.front()->set_value(_rbfs(children.front(), ...
```

where `state` inside of `_rbfs` is thus `children.front()`.

And in _rbfs, you sometimes delete `state`. So `children.front()` can be deleted and then called with `->set_value`. There's your problem.

Is there any reason why you calling `delete` at all?

Comment: The problem only occurs when the "delete" that is commented out is left uncommented. Otherwise, the algorithm works just fine. The reason I am calling delete is because I am not keeping track of the states in a stack because the memory overhead is too large (this is why I switched from iterative to recursive best-first search), so I can't just delete them when I'm done.